# adding image in coreData uiTableView xcode

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uiimageview, xcode7

I have an app in which I am storing and loading a textLabel and detailTextLabel to a UITableView with a prototype cell. All is working well.  I take a picture and store it within my documents directory and retrieve it and show it in a UIImageView. Again fine.
I am trying to save the image to my coreData and show it in the TableView but different pictures for each cell.
Here is my code for saving the image data to the coreData:

```
NSString *stringOneb = fileName2;
NSString *stringTwob = [stringOneb stringByAppendingString:@","];
NSString *stringFour = [stringTwob stringByAppendingString:yourName];

NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *slash3 = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images"];


NSString *fullPath1 = [slash3 stringByAppendingPathComponent:stringFour];
fullPath1 = [fullPath1 stringByAppendingFormat:@".png"];
//Now load the image at fullPath and install it into our image view's image property.
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath1]){

}
else {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullPath1];
    NSData *data5 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *cellimage = [UIImage imageWithData:data5];
    photoView2.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: fullPath1];
    myimageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(cellimage)];
}
 NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cell" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newDevice setValue:yourName forKey:@"name"];

        [newDevice setValue:Seven forKey:@"winloss"];

        [newDevice setValue:myimageData forKey:@"image"];

        NSError *error7 = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error7, [error7 localizedDescription]);
        }

    }
    else {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.tableDataMainView objectAtIndex:indexNumber ];
        [selectedDevice setValue:yourName forKey:@"name"];

        [selectedDevice setValue:Seven forKey:@"winloss"];

        [selectedDevice setValue:myimageData forKey:@"image"];
        NSError *error7 = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error7, [error7 localizedDescription]);
        }
```

I do not get any errors so I am assuming the image is getting saved.

This is how I am trying to retrieve the image in my TableView cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
NSManagedObject *device = [self.tableDataMainView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"name"]];
cell.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(16, 35, 200, 65);
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"winloss"]];
[cell.imageView setImage:[device valueForKey:@"image"]];

[cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


return cell;
```

}

If I reference an image in my main bundle it shows up but when I reference the valueForKey:@"image" I get nothing.

Not sure what I am doing wrong, could someone help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

got this figured out.  I just referenced the name of the image in my coredata and then loaded it into tableview